# "Отложенные параметры" командной строки в windows. Возможно ли?

Tags: php, linux, windows, cmd, gpg

Существует ситуация когда я пытаюсь вызвать команду с параметрами, после чего от меня требуется ввести еще сколько то символов с клавиатуры.
К примеру:

```
1    c:\> gpg -d wtf.crypt
2         Enter passphrase:
```

Когда мы работаем в командной строке, все очень даже не плохо. Можно просто ввести то, чего от нас ждут.

Но в своей задаче я хочу работать через php, к примеру. команду system().

То тогда получается, после выполнения приведенной в примере выше команды, страница подвиснет, и где то в фоне от меня будут ожидать ввода чего-нибудь.

Вопрос заключается в том, существует ли в системе windows и linux, какая нибудь вещь позволяющая предварительно установить параметры которые возможно использовать в случае появления вопросов после вызова команды?

Выдуманный пример: gpg -d wtf.crypt && [qwerty,y,y,1,1,3]
в квадратных скобка отложенные параметры, в порядке появления... существует ли что-то такое?

Comment: в линуксе есть команда [expect](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-expect_1/) - она собственно делает то, что нужно, только она немного наворочена. Она может читать строки от команды и корректно реагировать на них.

Comment: Благодарю вас, за подсказку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается через pipe (|)
Вот пример ввода пароля при тестирвоании архива:

```
echo infected|7z.exe t arc.zip
```

Собственно, echo выводит нужный текст, который через | передается в 7z.exe
Для GPG возможно потребуется использовать параметр --passphrase-fd

Comment: Спасибо. буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется перенаправление стандартного ввода. В Linux существует масса вариантов. Bash понимает:

Перенаправление из файла:

```
 cmd < file
```

Подключение вывода одной программы на ввод другой (труба или pipe):

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Ввод в программу данных записанных далее в следующих строках после команды (Here Document) :

```
cmd <<EOF
исходные
данные
EOF
```

Ввод одной строки (Here String):

```
cmd <<<'Исходные данные'
```

Во всех случаях, если программе понадобится больше данных, чем вы ей предоставите, она "упрётся" в конец файла, не сможет больше прочитать.

Программы  запрашивающие пароли (например ssh) часто делают так, что они сами обращаются для чтения данных к терминалу, откуда они были запущены, игнорируя стандарный ввод. Тут перенаправление ввода не поможет, это сделано специально, чтобы исключить возможность перехвата пароля. Тогда обычно у них есть альтернативные более безопасные способы задания пароля.